# select alternate alphabet from string of word in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to generate alternate alphabets from generated word string. E.g. Word is SPACEORION then alphabet should be like this SPCO. Because I need to generate client code as per their name. What would be the suitable solution?

Comment: You need to give more information.. what does "alternate" mean? Why SPCO? Does it have to be SPCO from that specific word and why? What would another word translate to? Do you want specific letters in a word to create the new "word or do you want it to be randomized? What is your goal? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari Alternate means suppose Word is SPACEORION then it should geneate word like this SACO. Here you see I have skipped all even  position character & word length will be 4. Client just need to give their name code like this will be generated automatically. I didn't tried anything since I don't have idea for what I want. I know to generate random characters

Comment: Check my answer, it should work now.. had to revise it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, from I understand, this might be what you want but the result of SPACEORION would be SAER and not SACO, so I hope I understood you correctly

```
string name = "SPACEORION ";
var shortName = "";
while (shortName.Length < 4)
{
    foreach (char ch in name.ToCharArray())
    {
        if (name.IndexOf(ch) % 2 == 0)
            {
                shortName += ch.ToString();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have little problem in this code. You have defined string size should be <= 4 then to it's getting whole words from string. Suppose user entered this name Demo Company then it creates code like this DMCMPY. It should create till DMCM only

Comment: No, i didn´t do <=, remove the equal mark(=), because otherwise it will continue when there already are 4 letters and returns 5 letters.. I dont understand how you can get a value of 6 letters though, unless you have somehow used an Array instead of string, since an array would start with index 0. That way you would get 6 letters: 0 to 5 in the array